# PowerShell Export-CSV creates empty file (finding email address)

Tags: powershell, csv

I tried to get email address from username, it works if I get the result from the console, but when I use export-csv it just created an empty file?

thansk!

```
$names=get-content c:\test\name.txt
foreach ($name in $names) {
Get-ADUser $name -Properties mail | select mail | Export-Csv -path         c:\test\email.csv
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting the exported file on each loop, you need to add an append to the export.

So it would be: **`export-csv -path path -append`**

Comment: ah..yes! sorry for the stupid question! thanks, @Nick-eagle